# Symfony 5 how to get isLike for posts for the current user?

Tags: symfony

I have Post entity and PostLike entity, could you give me a hint, how to get isLike in current post with current user from posts collection?

```
class Post implements AuthorInterface
{
 /**
 * @var int
 * @ApiProperty(identifier=false)
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private int $id;
/**
 * @var Uuid
 * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
 * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
 * @Groups({"post", "get", "get_post_with_comments", "get_posts_list"})
 */
private Uuid $uuid;
/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="posts")
 * @JoinColumn(name="author", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 * @Assert\NotNull
 * @Groups({"post", "get", "get_post_with_comments", "get_posts_list"})
 */
private User $author;
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Groups({"post", "get", "get_post_with_comments", "get_posts_list"})
 * @Assert\NotNull
 */
private string $title;
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 * @Groups({"post", "get", "get_post_with_comments", "get_posts_list"})
 * @Assert\NotNull
 */
private string $text;
/**
 * @var DateTimeInterface
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Groups({"post", "get", "get_post_with_comments", "get_posts_list"})
 * @Assert\NotNull
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private DateTimeInterface $createdAt;
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PostLike", mappedBy="post", cascade={"all"})
 */
private ?PersistentCollection $likes;

/**
 * @var int
 * @Groups({"post", "get", "get_post_with_comments", "get_posts_list"})
 */
private int $likesCount;

private bool|null $isLike = false;  // here need to be true or false (liked or not liked in GET all posts for current user

public function __construct(
)
{
    $this->uuid = new UuidV6();
    $this->createdAt = Carbon::now();
}

/**
 * @return UuidV6|Uuid
 */
public function getUuid(): UuidV6|Uuid
{
    return $this->uuid;
}

/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getAuthor(): User
{
    return $this->author;
}

/**
 * @param User $author
 */
public function setAuthor(User $author): void
{
    $this->author = $author;
}
/**
 * @return DateTimeInterface
 */
public function getCreatedAt(): DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * @return PersistentCollection|null
 */
public function getLikes(): ?PersistentCollection
{
    return $this->likes;
}

/**
 * @param PersistentCollection|null $likes
 * @return Post
 */
public function setLikes(?PersistentCollection $likes): static
{
    $this->likes = $likes;

    return $this;
}
/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getLikesCount(): int
{
    return count($this->likes);
}

public function getIsLike(): bool|null
{
    return $this->isLike;
}
public function setIsLike() // ??? what I have to write here ?

}
```

PostLike Entity

```
class PostLike implements AuthorInterface

{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=false)
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $id;

/**
 * @var Uuid
 * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
 * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
 * @Groups({"post", "get", "get_post_with_comments", "get_posts_list"})
 */
private Uuid $uuid;

/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="likes")
 * @JoinColumn(name="author", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 * @Assert\NotNull
 * @Assert\NotNull
 * @Groups({"post", "get", "get_post_with_comments", "get_post_like"})
 */
private User $author;

/**
 * @var Post
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="likes")
 * @JoinColumn(name="post", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 * @Assert\NotNull
 */
private Post $post;

/**
 * @var DateTimeInterface
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Groups({"post", "get", "get_post_like", "get_posts_list"})
 * @Assert\NotNull
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private DateTimeInterface $createdAt;

/**
 * @Groups({"get_post_like", "get_posts_list", "post", "get",})
 */
private bool $isLike;

/**
 * CommunityPostComment constructor.
 * @param User $author
 * @param Post $post
 */
public function __construct(
    User $author,
    Post $post
)
{
    $this->uuid = new UuidV6();
    $this->author = $author;
    $this->post = $post;
    $this->createdAt = Carbon::now();
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId(): int
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return UuidV6|Uuid
 */
public function getUuid(): UuidV6|Uuid
{
    return $this->uuid;
}

/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getAuthor(): User
{
    return $this->author;
}

/**
 * @param User $author
 */
public function setAuthor(User $author): void
{
    $this->author = $author;
}

/**
 * @return Post
 */
public function getPost(): Post
{
    return $this->post;
}

/**
 * @param Post $post
 */
public function setPost(Post $post): void
{
    $this->post = $post;
}

/**
 * @return DateTimeInterface|Carbon
 */
public function getCreatedAt(): DateTimeInterface|Carbon
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * @param DateTimeInterface|Carbon $createdAt
 */
public function setCreatedAt(DateTimeInterface|Carbon $createdAt): void
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
}

public function getIsLike(): bool
{
    return $this->isLike;
}

public function setIsLike(bool $like)
{
    $this->isLike = $like;
}
```

And my service

```
     /**
     * @param LikeInput $likeInput
     * @throws ORMException
     * @throws OptimisticLockException
     * @throws Exception
     * @return PostLike
     */
    public function addLike(LikeInput $likeInput): PostLike
    {
        if ($post = $this->postRepository->findOneByUuid(new UuidV6($likeInput->getPostUuid()))) {
            $like = $this->postLikeRepository->findOneBy(['author' => $likeInput->getAuthor(), 'post' => $post]);

            if ($like) {
                throw new Exception('You liked this post, can`t add more then 1 like.');
            }

            $like = new PostLike(
                $likeInput->getAuthor(),
                $post
            );

            $like->setIsLike(true);
            $this->postLikeRepository->save($like);
            $post->setIsLike(true);

            return $like;
        }

        throw new Exception('Can`t find this Post.');
    }
```

So, I have endpoint to add like to post, and it is working, but after I get all posts I see likes count and isLike is always false.

- I don't want to update Post entity by adding OneToOne relation to user, I feel, I can do it differently. *

please help.

PostLike response

```
{
    "uuid": "1ec485e5-5682-6c18-b229-...",
    "post": {
        "uuid": "1ec3d6b1-2e11-6592-bbee-....",
        "author": {
            "uuid": "1ec3d511-1701-6d62-a5fe-...",
            "fullName": "test",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "phone": "54498489489...",
            "dateOfBirth": "06/27/19.."
        },
        "topic": {
            "uuid": "1ec3d538-0cc7-6cbc-a286-...",
            "code": "Social...",
            "name": "Social..."
        },
        "title": "user 2 ...",
        "text": "user 2 ..",
        "createdAt": "2021-11-04T12:31:02.917944Z",
        "likesCount": 1,
        "isLike": true ->> and here is true, but from GET posts isLike = false
    },
    "createdAt": "2021-11-18T10:57:33.865956Z",
    "isLike": true
}
```

UPD:
I just wrote this code and it is working, but, as my mind, have to be result with ORM relation.

```
public function getPosts(User $user): array
    {
        $sql = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p as post, CASE WHEN COUNT(pl.id) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END AS isLike')
            ->leftJoin('p.likes', 'pl', Join::WITH, 'pl.author = :user AND pl.post = p.id')
            ->setParameter('user', $user->getId())
            ->orderBy('p.createdAt', 'DESC')
            ->groupBy('p.id')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        $posts = [];

        foreach ($sql as $data) {
            $post = $data['post'];
            $isLike = (bool)$data['isLike'] ?? false;
            $post->setIsLike($isLike);
            $posts[] = $post;
        }

        return $posts;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you have a `oneToMany` relation between `Post` and `PostLike` ? The count would just be the number of item in this collection. And what does isLike mean for `Post` since multiple user could either like or not your post. What does this boolean represent ?

Comment: yes, sorry, I have this relation, forgot paste, edited

Comment: Could you answer what isLike is supposed to be ? since multiple user could either like or not your post. What does this boolean represent. Is it something like 'at least one liked it' or ?

Comment: So you want to get all post that a user liked ?

Comment: This asked to do mine front devs. They want to render all posts for user with liked/not liked.
It is mean, I pres like for this post or not, 1 post I could like 1 time, and I see only mine likes I made (but all posts), but owner of this topic could see total count likes and who (users - nickname, avatar, date of like)

Comment: @Dylan Kas

I tried to login with user id = 2 and write code
`code
public function getIsLike()
    {
        return $this->likes->exists(function($key, $value) {
            return $value->getAuthor()->getId() === 2;
        });
    }
`
 and it show me all posts with isLike = true I've liked, login from another user and whole were false, it's good, but new question, how to set current user from Post entity ? using jwt